# Ruby regexp: why does this code not replace what is found but simply insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a ruby regexp searching for urls and I'm trying to replace them with a certain type of urls.

So this regexp detects any url but excludes the type I replace with.

However, when I try this code :

```
 s.sub(/(?!\S*\/el\/\d*)(?=(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<‌​>]+|(([^\s()<>]+|(([^\s()<>]+)))*))+(?:(([^\s()<>]+|(([^\s()<>]+)))*))))/, 'http://localhost:8080/el/133710')
```

if s is `s = "blablabla www.google.com bla http://localhost blabla"`

It should replace `www.google.com` with my string `http://localhost:8080/el/133710`

but I get this instead :

```
 "blablabla http://localhost:8080/el/133710www.google.com bla http://localhost blabla"
```

Comment: if your string is static type simply you can do `s.gusb!("www.google.com", "http://localhost:8080/el/133710")`

Comment: Thanks, but I found a workaround in my code but I'm still wondering why this behaves like this

Comment: please check you regexp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your intended capture `www.google.com` matches inside a lookahead `(?=)`, so it is not actually captured. `www.google.com` only works as a lookahead context. What is captured is only an empty string at the position of match. `sub` is replacing the captured string (which is an empty string) with `http://localhost:8080/el/133710`.

Comment: Oh so this is why! Thank you :)